# What actions get carried out on the files in /dev?

Tags: linux, drivers

What exactly does the files in /dev do? I'm having a difficult time understanding the relation between the files here, device drivers and the device.

Taking an example, what does /dev/hda do? does the hard disk driver read/write into it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is created by the hard disk driver so that higher-level drivers (device mapper, filesystem, etc.) can read/write/seek/tell/open/close/ioctl it.

(Actually, they operate on the device numbers directly, but it's a close-enough abstraction.)

Comment: oh..ok. So it's the interface between the higher level drivers in the kernel (logical) and the driver for the actual device.

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/` filesystem provides files that act as *interfaces* to the actual devices. It exists to facilitate using the hardware stuff with common IO functions and to identify the hardware to the user.

So when you act on the device file the driver has code that identifies what is happening and acts on the hardware to do what you asked.

You have character and block device files. Character devices write/read char by char (keyboards, mouses, modems, etc...) and block devices write/read in chunks of data. You also have some *pseudo* devices like `/dev/null` and `/dev/random` that are not associated with any hardware but work like one.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I'm writing something to a disk. The application prog/kernel writes something to the /dev/hda (or whichever) which in turn is read by the driver, interpreted and sent to the particular hard disk?

Comment: In a very summarized way, it is. It is more complex than that though and I recommend you reading a book on unix/linux kernel internals to see how they interact. 

http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

The comments on this code can show you an example of use of the dev filesystem.